# Rails polymorphic association error on user destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to link notifications to users like so.

```
  belongs_to :notified_by, class_name: 'User'
```

My user has_many notifications.

```
  has_many :notifications, dependent: :delete_all
```

The problem is, when I try to destroy a user, I get an error when it goes to delete all the notifications.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column notifications.user_id does not exist)
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" ...
```

There is no user_id in the Notifications table, just a notified_by_id. I have tried using that in place of notified_by, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the foreign key in the User model to recognize notified_by_id as the column to look for.

```
  has_many :notifications, foreign_key: 'notified_by_id', dependent: :delete_all
```